# Rows retrieve is not working as expected in Cloudpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I have a DE named `mock_data_only` and its external key is set to the same string.
I've tried doing a (SSJS) rows retrieve on this DE and wasn't able to do so. In cloudpage preview there's just a loading gif and if I looked into chrome's dev console, There was a 500 server error.

This is the script snippet I used.

```js
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.5");
try {
    var subsDE = DataExtension.Init("mock_data_only");
    var filter = {
        Property: "isSent",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: false,
    };
    var data = subsDE.Rows.Retrieve(filter);
    Write(Platform.Function.Stringify(data));
} catch (ex) {
    Write("An error has occurred: " + Stringify(ex));
}
```

However rows *lookup* worked as expected and I got the JSON string echoed

```js
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.5");
try {
    var subsDE = DataExtension.Init("mock_data_only");
    var data = subsDE.Rows.Lookup(["isSent"], [false]);
    Write(Platform.Function.Stringify(data));
} catch (ex) {
    Write("An error has occurred: " + Stringify(ex));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see there is extra comma at the end of last attribute pair  Value :false, (which tells the system that it is not complete yet and expects another attribute pair) Can you please try after removing comma or try below code for filter variable.

```js
var filter = {
        Property: "isSent",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: false
    };
```